# How to make such diagrams in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am just looking for a rough skeleton.

[image: sample image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Namaste! My experience with the overwhelming Tikz library is limited to graphs, which is why I came straight to TSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it looks like you're trying to draw a data field specification, you could use the [bytefield](https://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield?lang=en) library.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a small example so you can understand how to proceed:

1. using `calc`, I can define coordinates that are relative to each other by calculating their position via `$(nodeA) + (nodeB)$`.
2. I can then draw a `rectangle` between node `A` and `B` via `\draw (A) rectangle (B);`
3. I can add something to this rectangle by adding `node {some text}` **after** `rectangle`.
4. the option `midway` puts this node between `A` and `B`, midway...
5. using `\decorations.pathreplacing`, I can add a decoration I define.
6. `decorate` gives tikz the order to apply the decoration.
7. `decoration={...}` is what you puts between `A -- B`
8. I want a `brace` and then I toy around with it.
9. notice that I reused the point 3 of this list with the `node` after `--`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at ($(a) + (5,1)$);
\coordinate (c) at ($(b) + (1,-1)$);
\coordinate (d) at ($(c) + (4,1)$);
\coordinate (e) at ($(d) + (1,-1)$);
\draw   (a)rectangle node [midway]{Op code} 
        (b)rectangle node [midway]{...} 
        (c)rectangle node [midway]{any text I want } 
        (d) rectangle (e) ;

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}]  ($(b)- (0,1)$) -- node [midway,yshift=-20] {5}(a);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt, mirror}]  ($(b)- (0,1)$) -- (c);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt, aspect=00.1}]  ($(d)- (0,1)$) -- (c);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With use of nodes in chain. For braces is used Ti*k*Z library calligraphy˙˙ (that they are more fancy):

```
\documentclass[border=3.141502]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,%
                calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                }
                
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 0pt,
   start chain = A going right,
BC/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
        raise=#1,
              #2},% for mirroring of brace
        very thick,
        pen colour={#3}
        },
    box/.style = {draw, minimum width=#1, minimum height=7mm,
                  outer sep=0pt, font=\ttfamily,
                  on chain=A} 
                    ]
\node[box=40mm] {op code};      % A-1
\node[box=8mm]  {\dots};
\node[box=32mm] {};
\node[box=8mm]  {\dots};         
\node[box=48mm] {\dots};       % A-5

\draw [BC=2mm/mirror/red]  
    (A-1.south west) -- node[below=4mm] {5} (A-1.south east);
\draw [BC=2mm/mirror/red]
    (A-2.south west) -- node[below=4mm] {1} (A-2.south east);
\draw [BC=2mm/mirror/red]
    (A-3.south west) -- node[below=4mm] {4} (A-3.south east);
\draw [BC=2mm/mirror/red]
    (A-4.south west) -- node[below=4mm] {\dots} (A-4.south east);
\draw [BC=2mm/mirror/red]
    (A-5.south west) -- node[below=4mm] {} (A-5.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]